# Odoo/Openerp: filter view data via python code

Tags: odoo

In Odoo/Openerp i created a kanban view to display some data. Now i managed to change this view with the `fields_view_get` based on context data.

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type=False, context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    res = super(esfyt_subscription_template,self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if context.get('partner_id', False):
        partner_id = context.get('partner_id', False)
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        if view_type == 'kanban':
            for node in doc.xpath("//div[@class='oe_module_vignette']"):
                new_addition = etree.SubElement(node, 'button', {'string' : 'Subscribe', 'type' : 'object', 'name' : 'action_subscribe'})
                new_addition.text = 'Subscribe'
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

But i need to do the same with the data.  i need to limit some data based on context, o certain models(or rows) arent loaded in the view.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

To filter records based on the context, you have to override the search() method

To filter data based on the context, you have to override the read()/browse() methods

Comment: could you please give me an example for read and browse? I'm using this but it isn't working: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9117837/

Comment: Your method is good, but the error is not due to this method.